# Filter a broadcasted property in Angular 9

Tags: arrays, angular, filtering, broadcast

I have a dbService that calls the database!

//DB service code -----------------------

```
 private changedEvents = new BehaviorSubject<IEvent[]>(null);
  broadCastEvents = this.changedEvents.asObservable();

  getEvents() {
    this.http.get<IEvent[]>(this.configUrl + 'Event/GetEvents').subscribe(
      (data: IEvent[]) => {
        this.changedEvents.next(data)
      });
  }
```

In my component on ngOnInit I starts listening to this

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dbService.broadCastEvents.subscribe(data => {
      this.events = data;
    })
   // this.dbService.getEvents();
  }
```

Now all of this working like a charm! But now I'm only interested in records where this.events.type == 2

I tried by a standard filtering like below!

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dbService.broadCastEvents.subscribe(data => {
      this.events = data.filter(event => event.eventTypeRefId == 2);
    })
   // this.dbService.getEvents();
  }
```

But it results in the following Error!? Any ideas how to this in a better way (that works :-))

```
core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null
    at SafeSubscriber._next (start-training.component.ts:26)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:81)
    at BehaviorSubject.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at Observable._subscribe (Observable.js:76)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways for it. One way is to use array `filter` like you did. Other way would be to use RxJS `filter` pipe as shown by @enno.void. However both these methods might still throw an error when the notification is `null`. And since the default value of your `BehaviorSubject` is null, there is high probability of hitting the error again.

One workaround for it is to use [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with buffer 1 instead. It's similar to `BehaviorSubject` in that it holds/buffer the last emitted value and emits it immediately upon subscription, except without the need for a default value. So the need for initial `null` value is mitigated.

Try the following

```js
private changedEvents = new ReplaySubject<IEvent[]>(1);
broadCastEvents = this.changedEvents.asObservable();
...
```

Now the error might still occur if you were to push `null` or `undefined` to the observable. So in the filter condition you could check for the truthiness of the value as well.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dbService.broadCastEvents.subscribe(data => {
    this.events = data.filter(event => {
      if (event) {
        return event.eventTypeRefId == 2;
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I even understood by your explanation why it did not work! Thank's a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dbService.broadCastEvents.pipe(filter(event => event.eventTypeRefId == 2)).subscribe(data => {
    this.events = data
  })
 // this.dbService.getEvents();
}
```

Reference:
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators